# How to integrate Payfort SDK to iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, payment-gateway, payfort

I am trying to integrate payfort SDK to my iOS project.
I am using xcode 9.0 and swift 4.0.
I followed the instruction on payfort docs. But still can't see the module name of payfort in my project.
This is the guide https://docs.payfort.com/pdf/FORT_Mobile-SDK_iOS_Integration_Guide_v_2.0.pdf

But it showing only PayFortLogo.png when import module. See in below picture.

[image]

Comment: this is sdk objective c add `header bridge`

Answer (score 2):

Payfort guide to integration ios mobile SDK 
Please the doc first:

https://docs.payfort.com/pdf/FORT_Mobile-SDK_iOS_Integration_Guide_v_1.3.pdf

1- TO intregrate Payfort SKD follow the following steps. Don't use any other method.

 Downloaded iOS SDK from official link.

 Unzip the downloaded iOS SDK.

 Drag the PayFortSDK.framework & PayFortSDK.bundle to Frameworks in Project Navigator.

o Create a new group Frameworks if it does not exist.

o Choose Create groups for any added folders.

o Make Sure to select Copy files if needed.

2- Copy PayfortView2.xib & PayfortView2_ar.xib from the project view or ask Payfort support team for it, Now use them in your project.

3- Use your custom view for PayfortView by mapping it with PayfortView.h using Payfort framework Connect all outlets with your custom view.

```
paycontroller?.setPayFortCustomViewNib("PayFortView2")
```

4- Download "JVFloatLabeledTextField" library from github or use pod for it.

5- Use JVFloatLabeledTextField instead of PFKJVFloatLabeledTextField change PayfortView2.xib and PayfortView2_ar.xib class in "Identify Inspactor" from xcode.

6- Now open "PayFortView.h" from ~/PayFortSDK.framework/Header/PayFortView.h in your project change outlet PFKJVFloatLabeledTextField to JVFloatLabeledTextField

Bellow is the link that I have integrated to my demo project:
Change your payfort account.
https://github.com/bhoopend232/PayfortDemo.git

Comment: Now Payfort fixed the issue the above solution not work.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these below steps in swift4  and Objective-c we are easily acheive payfort sdk integrate to your projects.It will help full mostly.

1. .Downloaded iOS SDK from official link.

   1. List item
   2. Unzip the downloaded iOS SDK.
   3. List itemDrag the PayFortSDK.framework & PayFortSDK.bundle to Frameworks in Project Navigator.

Copy PayfortView2.xib & PayfortView2_ar.xib from the project of github to  drag into  your project.

paycontroller?.setPayFortCustomViewNib("PayFortView2")

Download "JVFloatLabeledTextField" library from github Or use pod for it.

Use JVFloatLabeledTextField in place of PFKJVFloatLabeledTextField change PayfortView2.xib and PayfortView2_ar.xib in "Identify Inspactor" from xcode.

IF we are using sand box account and production account use seperate urls to use 
For sandBox: 
https://sbpaymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi
For Production:
https://paymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi

While check this below pdf file for passing parameters and response 
https://docs.payfort.com/pdf/FORT_Mobile-SDK_iOS_Integration_Guide_v_2.9.pdf

just in the success response we call the xib file .Then it will automatically redirect to card details page.

If you want source code  just check this below repository in swift4

```
https://github.com/SRReddy411/PayFortPaymentDemo
```

If you want objective c then we will check this one

```
https://github.com/SRReddy411/payfort-Objective-c
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs properly. Section 4.2, page 10. The framework is written in Objective-C and you have a Swift project, so you need a `Bridging-Header`.

[image]

One of the hundreds of tutorial on how to setup a `Bridging-Header: https://youtu.be/lon5YVMUxHQ